# Elegant way to print HTML Lists with Ruby + ERB

Tags: ruby, erb

I have the following code

```
<% if items.any? %>
    <ul class="level1">
        <% items.each do |item| %>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="#"><%= item.text %></a>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>   
<% end %>
```

While this works, I was wondering if there was a way to make it more elegant. The `if` and then `each` is not very pretty...

Anyone knows a more elegant syntax?

Comment: That looks like erb, not HTML. There are haml, slim, etc.

Comment: Corrected tag and title. Thanks.

Comment: It looks good to me!

Answer (score 3):

Try this, [`based on`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5637#issuecomment-4777920):

```
<% content_tag(:ul, class: 'level1') do %>
   <% content_tag_for(:li, items, class: "item") do |item|
      <%= link_to item.text, '#' %>
   <% end %>
<% end if items.any? %>
```

5 lines, no extra partials, only rails helpers.

Comment: Just 2 levels... that is so far the best one :)

Comment: I personally think the readability is better with the `if items.any?` wrapping the block, but there's no doubt that is *super concise*. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458631/elegant-way-to-print-html-lists-with-ruby-erb/35458968#comment58613634_35458631), you could use [Slim](http://slim-lang.com):

```
- if items.any?
  ul.level1
    - items.each do |item|
      li.item
        a href="#"
          = item.text
```

or [Haml](http://haml.info):

```
- if items.any?
  %ul.level1
    - items.each do |item|
      %li.item
        %a{href: "#"}= item.text
```

Both produce nicely formatted HTML.

Comment: Well, I do not want to change my whole templating engine just because of this... :) But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That actually looks sufficiently elegant to me already, but you could do this to make a *little* cleaner:

```
<% if items.any? %>
  <ul class="level1">
    = render items
  </ul>   
<% end %>
```

And then have your `li` code in a partial called `_items.html.erb`, like so:

```
<li class="item">
  <a href="#"><%= item.text %></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Well, it is a line shorter, but an extra file... Thanks for the suggestion, though :)

Comment: Ha, yeah, like I said, what you've got already is sufficiently elegant. When you only need to iterate over/add simple `li`s, 9 lines is pretty clean. :-D

Answer (score 0):

I would go into something like this:

```
if items.any?
  content_tag(:ul, class: 'level1') do
    items.each do |item|
      concat content_tag(:li, class: 'item', item)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: well, it is just another command to print the same. It is basically the same instructions with synonym methods.

Comment: @Dbugger what exactly are you looking for? Maybe we're not understanding what "elegant" means to you. You still have to tell the computer what you want it to do. :-)